# When does an order ID get reserved in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders

When does Magento 2 determine which customer gets the next consecutive order ID? Is it yielded from the quote `entity_id` or does it assign to whichever order is completed first?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the order id (`entity_id`) is the primary key (autoincrement) of the `sales_order` table.
This means first come, first served.
The id is incremented when an order is stored in the database.

On the other hand, there is the `increment_id` on the order.
This works differently. It is reserved during the checkout process by calling the method `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::reserveOrderId`.
This means that once the number is reserved is it not changed. That's why you may find gaps in the `increment_id` sequence. There might be people that don't finish the checkout process but had ids reserved.

THe method is called in the multishipping checkout in `Magento\Multishipping\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping::_prepareOrder`, in `\Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout::start` and in `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement:reserveOrderId()`.

If you want you can dig further to see when is the actual moment when the increment id is reserved.

Comment: when this function is called? \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::reserveOrderId
for some quotes, reserved_order_id is set, and for some quotes it is not.

Comment: $quote->reserveOrderId()->save(); worked for me, thanks

Comment: @Marius, What are the scenarios for missing order number in Magento 2? I'm getting this issue randomly but not sure why it's happening? Is there something we can resolve this from our end?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know

Comment: I have noticed that when reserved_order_id assigns to quote before redirecting the customer to external payment method but for any reason if user doesn't complete order misses order id

Comment: Could Magento be modified in such way that it would not leave gaps to order numbering? Would that cause problems or would it be difficult?